# How to make an element move on the right after an input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, cursor

I am developing a project, and I made a custom input element. The problem is that whenever I try to add text, it shifts to the next line, so I was making it stop and shifting the position whenever input is added. I am making it go to the right whenever input is added(in my project, you can only add 1 text at a time). For the first few times, it works, but after 4 inputs, the space between the cursor(made by me/custom) and the closest text becomes more than it should be, for now, for a new input, the code adds `5px` to the current margin, and the problem occurs, if I add `4px`, the text moves too far. Is there any way that I can make my custom cursor move just as needed for it to look good.

Code(Note: I have code that is not used/is not needed, but I am scared that if I remove anything, something will go wrong, also you need to have a full page to see the cursor, else you can't see it, and the problem with it going below is something I have to solve once this problem is solved):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="background-color:black; margin:0;padding:0;" lang="en-US">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="icon" href="icon.png"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="description" content="Description"/>
<title>MyTitle</title>
<style>
a{
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#heading{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 420 bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px red;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#description{
    color: green;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 69 bold;
    font-family: serif;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#cursor{
    text-align: initial;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
  font-weight: 35;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #2E3D48;
  -webkit-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  -moz-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  -ms-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  -o-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
}
#field{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    
}
#fieldDiv{
    background-color: #968786;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 28px;}

@keyframes "blink" {
  from, to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
  from, to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes "blink" {
  from, to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes "blink" {
  from, to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes "blink" {
  from, to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
}
#cursorContainer{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
}
#bton{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="heading">
        Heading
    </h1>
    <p id="description">Description</p>
    <div id="fieldDiv">
        <p id="field"></p><p id="cursorContainer" onclick="hideCursor()"><span id="cursor">|</span></p>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button id="bton" onclick="change();">
        <!--Always add the script on the bottom of the BODY tag since it contains the script-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var marginNum = screen.width/2;
            const screenWidth = screen.width;
            function checkCtrlA(){
                var ctrlPressed = false;
                window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
                    if(e.keyCode == 17){
                        ctrlPressed = true;
                    }
                });
                if(ctrlPressed){
                    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
                        if(e.keyCode == 65){
                            hideCursor();
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
            window.onload = function(){
                const cursor = document.getElementById("cursor");
                const widthNeeded = innerWidth/2;
                cursor.style.marginLeft = widthNeeded.toString() + "px";
                cursor.style.cursor = "default";

            };
            const divToHide = document.getElementById("fieldDiv");
            divToHide.onclick = hideCursor;
            function printf(val){
                console.log(val);
            }
            document.getElementById("fieldDiv").addEventListener('click', function(){
                const element = document.getElementById("cursor");
                element.style.visibility = "hidden";
            });
            document.getElementById("fieldDiv").addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
                const element = document.getElementById("cursor");
                element.style.visibility = "hidden";
            });
            document.getElementById("fieldDiv").addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
                const element = document.getElementById("cursor");
                element.style.visibility = "visible";
            });
            var currentText = document.getElementById("field").textContent;
            function change(){
                movePosCursor();
                currentText = document.getElementById("field").textContent += "a";
                document.getElementById("cursor").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
            function movePosCursor(){
                const element = document.getElementById("cursor");
                marginNum += 5;
                var widthInPx = marginNum.toString() + "px";
                element.style.marginLeft = widthInPx;

            }
            function hideCursor(){
                const element = document.getElementById("cursor");
                element.style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
            checkCtrlA();
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```